# How to remove this extra trailing space at the end of each line in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print this pattern using print() function in python3.

```
        0
      0 1 0
    0 1 2 1 0
  0 1 2 3 2 1 0
    0 1 2 1 0
      0 1 0
        0
```

the following are the two ways I implemented this.

> numeric approach

```
limit = int(input())
space = '  '
for i in range(0, limit + 1):
    print(space * (limit - i), end='')

    for j in range(2 * i + 1):
        if j > i:
            print(i - (j - i), end=' ')
        else:
            print(j, end=" ")
    print()


for i in range(0, limit)[::-1]:
    print(space * (limit - i), end='')

    for j in range(2 * i + 1)[::-1]:

        if j > i:
            print(i - (j - i), end=' ')
        else:
            print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

> string and list comprehension approach

```
gap = '  '
y = int(input())
y = y + 1
for n in range(1, y + 1):
    str1 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in list(range(n)))
    str2 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in list(range(n - 1))[::-1])
    print(gap * (y - n) + str1 + " " + str2.strip())

for n in range(1, y)[::-1]:
    str1 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in list(range(n)))
    str2 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in list(range(n - 1))[::-1])
    print(gap * (y - n) + str1 + " " + str2.strip())
```

the pattern is printing right but when I am submitting this to online judge it do not accept.

```
wrong answer 1st lines differ - expected: '    0', found: '    0 '
```

it expects to remove that extra space after the 0.

**PROBLEM:** In both of the code snippet I am unable to remove the last line extra space.
 I do not know how to achieve this Pattern and also not to have that extra space after the number at the end of each line.

Comment: [str.rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) might also help

Comment: The issue is `+ str1 + " "` where `str2.strip()` is ''. You just need to remove that space if `str2.strip() is None/''`

Comment: @mad_ [Nope.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) strip removes "the leading and trailing characters". `rstrip()` is the way to go as another commentator pointed out.

Comment: much thanks rstrip() did the trick.

Comment: You can remove the `list()` calls on your ranges if you want. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be the expression `gap * (y - n) + str1 + " " + str2.strip()`. For the first line, `str` is null, so you have `str1` followed by a space, followed by nothing, which means that you have a space at the end of your line. The solution is to add the lists together first, then `join`:

```
for n in range(1, y + 1):
    list1 = [str(e) for e in list(range(n))]
    list2 = [str(e) for e in list(range(n - 1))[::-1]]
    print(gap * (y - n)+" ".join(list1+list2))
```

BTW, an alternative to `list(range(n - 1))[::-1]` is  `list(range(n-2,-1,-1))`.

You can also combine list comprehensions with various tricks, such as

`[str(e) if e < n else str(2*n-e) for e in range(2*n+1) ]`